# Rewrite URLs without file extension (including across sub-directories)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file on my server (It's a tweak of code I found on-line somewhere, for the life of me I cannot remember where) and I'm not quite sure how to amend it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It basically grabs the URL, removes any trailing `/`, adds `.php` to the end of it, goes to that page, but then displays the link with a `/` instead of the extension in the URL bar (from what I can tell).

It works really well, bar two annoying niggles:

- I can then only have `.php` files within that directory. Any others break.
- The `.htaccess` file needs to be copied to EVERY subdirectory to function.

Can this script be improved upon at all, to do the following:

- Put it in my root (`/`) directory and have it work in to all sub-folders?
- Allow multiple file extensions within each directory? (e.g. some `.php`, some `.html`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work from your `DocumentRoot` and will add all the extensions:

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```